# $n>3$ be an odd integer , $k,t$ be smallest positive integers such that both $tn , kn+1$ are perfect squares . Then is $n$ prime iff $k,t>n/4$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $n>3$ be an odd integer , $k,t$ be smallest positive integers such that both $tn , kn+1$ are perfect squares . Then is $n$ prime if and only if both $k,t$ are greater than $n/4$ ?

Comment: Given the prime decomposition of $n$, finding $t$ is easy (the prime decomposition of $t$ consists of one of each prime that has an odd exponent in $n$), so $t\gt n/4$ means $n$ is square-free (and vice versa). I have no idea how to be clever about finding $k$.

Answer (score 1):

First we prove that for all composite numbers we can find $t$ or $k$ less than or equal to $\frac{n}{4}$

1. If the $n$ can be written as $n=p^m \tag{1}$ for some integer $m>1$ and a prime $p$ then we can take $t=$ if $m$ is even or $t=p\leq \sqrt[m] n\leq \sqrt[3] n\leq \frac{n}{4}$ if $m$ is odd.
2. If $(1)$ is not true then we can write $n=pq$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1$ and $p>1,q>1$, so using Bézout's identity there exists two integers $x$ and $y$ such that:
   $$xp-yq=2$$
   and Bezout's identity gives us in addition $|x|\leq \frac{q}{2}$ and $|y|\leq \frac{p}{2}$ so we can take $k=xy$ because:
   $$xypq+1=(xp-2)xp+1=(xp-1)^2 $$

Second assume that the integers $k$ and $t$ exist for a prime $n$ and we prove that $k,t>\frac{n}{4}$ clearly $t>\frac{n}{4}$ and we have also $kn=x^2-1$ for some $x$ because  $n$ divides $x-1$ or $x+1$ we have  $n\leq x+1$ and from this  we conclude that $k\geq x-1\geq n-2 \geq \frac{n}{4}$ (n\geq3 in the question)